# How to configure spring security in a web application?

Tags: java, spring-security

How to configure Spring Security in a web application?
I added three JAR files to my lib: security-core, security-web and security-config. Now what do I need to add in configuration XML file with a custom login page?

Comment: Have you read anything about it? Or tried some code?

Comment: Have you had a look at the spring security tutorial? http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=spring+security+tutorial&aq=0&oq=spring+security+tu&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3j62.7012&sugexp=chrome,mod=17&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ref : http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Spring</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml                          
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.jsp"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" filters="none"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="admin"  authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

app-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <task:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"   class= "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="cache"  value= "true"/>
        <property name="prefix" value= ""/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
        <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="rc"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```